# Application architecture with AWS Lambda

Tags: architecture, aws-lambda

This is related to AWS Lambda implementation. I am working on some lambda function in .netcore. There are 14 different travel destinations which has different rules and regulations related to fare, hotel booking, rent etc. I have a library that handles these rules per travel destination. I have total 14 class handlers to these travel destinations in that library. At the end when some agent want to book more than one destination, they need to submit them at the end for further process being handled by a separate library.
Right now, I have 14 different menu items clicking on which opens up selection process for travel destinations. We are trying to convert this app to use AWS lambda. Initially, we thought to have a single lambda per travel destination; ending up to have 14 different lambdas and a separate lambda for further processing when itinerary get submitted for further process. So, when any user click on any travel menu item, the rules and regulation, logic will be handled by designated lambda function.

However, there is one more functionality that agent can save their itinerary and schedule them in future. Such itinerary must get processed only on the date when they are scheduled. Suppose there are 5 destinations configured in one of the itinerary then designated 5 lambda will process these destination for rules and regulation, and then it needs to be submitted to further processing lambda.
Here is the issue, these 5 lambdas are going to run async/simultaneously. How can I tell these 5 lambdas to wait for each other till all 5 completes their work and then separate lambda can be initiated for submit/further process? Because further processing can only be done once all 5 travel destinations are finished processing with individual lambda functions.

I tried looking for lambda step functions, but that will kill beauty of aync mode. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Putting it to more short and simple words, I have to simultaneously process travel destination lambdas and once all finished then send all to further processing lambda. I need to find some mechanism that will make all travel destination lambdas  to wait for each other to finish so that once all are finished with their work then send all to further processing lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Step-Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html), these will allow you set up workflows as a state machine allowing you to coordinate and pass data between your lambdas. You can also have it pass data to other services such as ECS, SNS,and SQS.

Comment: If I use State Function then I will have to process lambda by lambda, is this correct? Taking above example, Is it possible that I process destination lambda parallel?